# Why does the same file appear a different size when cloning versus downloading from browser?

Tags: java, file, github, size, byte

I recently cloned a repository from GitHub and checked a specific Java class in my file explorer to find it was **2,917 bytes**.

On my web browser, in the same branch, I viewed the same class as "Raw" and "Saved As" a .java. When I checked this in the file explorer, it appeared as **2,817 bytes**.

There are no disparities in the code; both files are identical. Where did the extra 100 bytes come from?

Comment: We'd need to see the specific repository and file, but typically it comes from git's automatic translation of newline standards. Windows newlines take 2 bytes, while other systems' newlines take 1 byte. When cloning the repo using git, it will translate the repo's newlines to your preferred OS' newlines, unless you configure it to not do so.

Comment: @kumesana I think your comment would be even more useful as an answer.